# как синхронизировать меню и location в AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Пишу приложение в котором адрес (location) зависит от 4 параметров: раздел, сортировка 1, сортировка 2, страница.

хочу чтоб маршрут выглядел например так - http://mysite.com/rozdel/sort1/sort2/page3

Для разделов это не проблема, можно просто добавить в `href` инфу (допустим, есть `<a ng-href="/category">Раздел 1</a>`). Но вот как потом когда пользователь выберет сортировку, либо страницу, добавить это в их `href`, чтоб их `href` базировался на основе href раздела, например `<a ng-href="/category/sort1">Раздел 1</a>`

как такое реализовать на AngularJS? писать ф-ю для замены URL с помощью `$location`?

Comment: Может быть есть смысл воспользоваться чем-то типа solotable, мгновенно сортирует таблицу из 10000 строк. Т.е. получаем из раздела весь список на страницу и потом его сортируем как угодно.

Comment: @fedornabilkin A если загрузить надо примерно 100Мб???

Comment: 100мб для любой скорости накладно. Если в разделе действительно инфы столько, либо делить на подразделы, либо выводить минимум информации (название, цена, размер) и отправлять на деталку.